# Robocopy Delta Copy over network

Tags: windows, copy, robocopy

We manage a client site that has a file & print server on-site and our intention is to move their files / data to a centralised server at our data center.

As the client has a very slow internet connection (adsl @ 5mbps), my boss has visited site to copy the data to an External USB Hard Disk.

I've copied the data my boss had collected to the centralised server at the data center via USB. I now need to copy all the new files / changed files since my boss had taken the initial copy/seed of the data over the internet. I will need to conduct the cutover data copy using Robocopy (Over the internet, using UNC path - We have a VPN connection setup to link the new servers).

My question is, will the below robocopy command do delta's (Keeping in mind that the original copy method to usb was done using the standard windows drag and drop method):

robocopy "\Source" "\Destination" /e /np /r:1 /w:1 /xo /log:BackupLog.txt

I only want to copy new files / folders that exist at the source using robocopy over the internet, and not the whole 1TB data set.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using Robocopy? Bittorrent Sync should copy only changed files, and may only the changed parts of files, not sure. Dropbox would be another way, or rsync. It depends on your requirements. Both will be fine with a slow connection, it'll just take longer. Alternately you could use a backup program that supports incremental backups.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is fine but /xo is extraneous.  Robocopy by default will only copy new or changed files.  I'm also assuming you did it this way to get the files to the external USB?  The reason I state that is to make sure the original timestamps and security were copied (if necessary).

Comment: he mentioned that it was drag & dropped, so probably not.

Comment: @DanPritts - I should read things in parenthesis more... :)